# Create page that is not deletable

Tags: pages

How can I mark a page as "no deletable" in the wordpress database? I've already seen [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12650079/5626274), but it requires a plugin. Is there really no way beyond a plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the filters supplied via the delete/trash functions of WordPress API: [`wp_trash_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_trash_post/) and [`wp_delete_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_delete_post/):

```
function prevent_post_trash_delete($bool, $post){
    $posts_to_keep = [30];

    if ( isset( $post->ID ) && in_array($post->ID, $posts_to_keep) ) {
        return false;
    }

    return $bool;
}

add_filter('pre_delete_post', 'prevent_post_trash_delete', 10, 2);
add_filter('pre_trash_post', 'prevent_post_trash_delete', 10, 2);
```

You can pass an array of IDs (so be it post, page, or any other post type) through the `$posts_to_keep` variable.

That way they will throw a notice when a user tries to delete them via the dashboard. You can't prevent plugins using direct SQL queries from deleting these pages.